# Pie chart with list

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

Hi my friends I'm very new on kibana.
I want to create a pie chart with a field who contains a list, like this:

```
[passed, passed, passed, passed, failed, failed, failed, passed, passed, passed, passed, passed, passed, passed, failed, passed, passed, failed, passed, passed, passed, passed, passed, passed]
```

When I create the pie chart I get a 50/50 percentage that is wrong because in this hit on this field there are 19 passed and 5 failed like the list above.
I am slice by the field that contains the list and size by count of record. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help.

Comment: which version of ES you are using ?

Comment: I am using 7.15.1 in kibana and elastic